# How do I turn off the built in macOSD shortcut for Minimise ('Opt' + 'Cmd' + "M")

Tags: keyboard, macos, shortcut

I want to use the built in Google Docs shortcut for "Add Comment…" (I don't think I can change those). It is the same as the one Apple assigned for minimise documents ('Opt' + 'Cmd' + "M").

I've been through all the System Prefs tabs relating to keyboard shortcuts I can find and I cannot find a way to change or disable this built in behaviour. Is there a way?

Comment: I don't advise doing this because Apple developers that adhere to the [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/overview/themes/).   Devs expect those shortcuts to be there and changing them could have adverse results.

Comment: This is an absurd comment @Allan. (I first read the HIG a couple of decades ago BTW). Apple themselves provide this functionality and I've used it in many, many cases to fix problems with Apple and other software and keyboard conflicts b/w apps, to remove annoying shortcuts or just to add shortcuts. The times it doesn't work are when Apple in their wisdom use identical sub-menu item labels more than once in their application's menus (Numbers for example), or when the short cut is 'hardwired' not menu driven, for example 'Opt' + 'Left Arrow' inserts a column left of current cell (& pauses app).

Comment: but 'Opt' + 'Left Arrow'  is also the macOS system wide shortcut to move the cursor in a text field one word to the left of current cursor position. I'm hardwired to do that and in Numbers sometimes it does that but the initial first use of it inserts columns which always pauses the screen for a couple of seconds as it processes the command, then a second for each additional keystroke I've already typed before that "Gotcha" moment is reflected on the screen.

Answer (score 2):

Setting a new custom shortcut frees the old one to pass through to the application.

- What if you set minimize to be triggered by Control + Option + Command + Shift + L in Apple Keyboard Preferences?

You can set that just for your web browser(s) for using Google Docs or you can set it system wide as you find works best for your brain.

Comment: I don't use Google Docs much (in fact I avoid it whenever I can), but they must have a way to reassign that shortcut or a knowledge article explaining how to change shortcuts on MacOS - tons and tons of Google's employees use macOS at work so you know you're probably not the first person and certainly someone with some real influence on product design or documentation has this need and may have documented or fixed it on Google side.

Comment: They don't, all I could find in their forums was discussions from people shocked that there was a conflict between Doc subscript "Command" + ","  Safari's browser preferences… that's the most common App Preferences key shortcut allocation on macOS software and an "Expert user" was surprised

Comment: I didn't know what the Minimise command that was called by the "Option" + "Command" + "M" shortcut. Turns out it is called "Minimize All". So I was able to replace it.

Answer (score 1):

Answered here on [Apple Communities](https://discussions.apple.com/message/33534363#message33534363). As above but the critical missing info is the command that one needs to change the shortcut for is called "**Minimize All**" (note USA Spelling if you have a auto-correct set to UK/Aust spelling). Change this to whatever that is not a conflict with anything else you use, as you best set it for All Applications if it's not something you use (I hate minimisation via shortcuts).

Comment: I hear you. I only ever hide with the keyboard. Only the mouse seems to work for my brain to want to minimize something, but I’m sure there are huge fans of minimize from the keyboard out there, too.

Comment: yeah main issue is the conflict not which way is best.